# Missing 3 required positional arguments Python

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror

Right so I'm working on a python code and I get this type error, "TypeError: printE() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'emp2', 'emp3', and 'emp4'"

```
for emmp in employee:
    print(printE(emmp))

def printE(emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4):

    emp1 = "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(emp1[0], ' '.join(emp1[1:-2]))
    emp2 = "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(emp2[1], ' '.join(emp2[2:-3]))
    emp3 = "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(emp3[2], ' '.join(emp3[3]))
    emp4 = "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(emp4[3], ' '.join(emp4[0:-1]))
    print("{:10s} {:15s} {:5s} {:15s}".format(emp4[0], emp1[1], emp2[2], emp3[3]))
```

Any sort of help will be much appreciated!

Comment: what is employee in code ??

Comment: That is a tuple where I have read a file into

Comment: Please show one such tuple - it would be good to know what it would look like :)

Comment: This is one tuple "17520 Business 47500 Jordan Jones"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for emmp in employee:
    print(printE(emmp))
```

as you say employee is tuple like

**Case 1**

```
employee = ('E1','E2'.....)
```

**Note:** when you iterator over tuple using for loop it gives you single employ **E1** or next time **E2** so on

And your function **printE** takes four arguments and you call it with the only single argument  'E1' or next time 'E2' so on.

So it gives you error that remaining argument are missing.

**Case 2**

if employee is tuple of tuple then look this example

```
employee = (('E1',10,"b10",20),('E1',10,"b10",20))

def printE(emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4):
    """ do what ever you want to do with param meters """

    return emp1 ,emp2 ,emp3, emp4

for emmp in employee:
    print(printE(*emmp))
```

**Output**

```
('E1', 10, 'b10', 20)                                                                                                   

('E1', 10, 'b10', 20)
```

Comment: Oh yeah because then the tuple basically resets itself. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: @DangerousDaz check case 2

Comment: I've got a problem now where it says "TypeError: employeePrint() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given" my tuple has got names and it counts them both. Any ideas how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

in a for loop, you will get one employee at a time. so the function is getting only one argument. The error is clear, that 3 arguments are missing. try passing the employees directly into the function

Answer (score 0):

printE method takes 4 arguments and in your loop your only giving one. Or if in loop 'emmp' is a list of four elements. Then try calling like 'printE(*emmp)'.